# Font issue! HTML5 template font is different than corresponding Umbraco template

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, razor, umbraco

I seem to be running into a frustrating issue with font styles when converting an html5 template to umbraco. When all styles and scripts of the html5 template are copied into the appropriate scripts and css folders in Umbraco, everything appears to be correct, except when running the application the font style for everything under the header appears to be a different font than the original html5 template.

Please note that the html5 template was converted to an umbraco template by creating a homepage template in cshtml.

It's strange. I'm wondering if the font isn't supported by the server or cshtml (which both don't make sense and are probably unlikely issues). I assume that the font style would be supported since the HTML5 template doesn't seem to have an issue when running off of localhost.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting the font files yourself and not loading from Google fonts or another 3rd party CDN, check the file format is allowed in your web.confg.

Under `staticContent` ensure the following are present:

```
<remove fileExtension=".woff" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
<remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/font-sfnt" />
```

If you are using any other font file formats, they will also need to be added as an allowed file type.

Comment: I have tried loading the font files from Google and hosting them myself via localhost...it appears that when I run the solution, the body and footer font are incorrect (I'm assuming IIS issue), but when index.html via a browser the fonts appear as they should. So you are saying to host the font files myself and then add that to the web.config?